# add another resource in the ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

We have already an function app plan named ""ap-d-function1". we want to create another app plan named ""ap-d-function2". How can I include "ap-d-function2" in the existing parameters template? I tried with following but did not work.

```
"hostingPlanName": {
      "value": "ap-d-function1"
    },
    "hostingPlanSku": {
      "value": "P2V2"
    },
```

updated parameter template:

```
"hostingPlanName": {
      "value": "ap-d-function1","ap-d-function2"
    },
    "hostingPlanSku": {
      "value": "P2V2"
    },
```

tried this too

```
"hostingPlanName": [
{
  "value": "ap-d-function1",
    },
{
  "value": "ap-d-function2",
    }
],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an array type for this, e.g. declared as:

```
"hostingPlanNames": {
  "type": "array"
}
```

Then in the parameter file:

```
"hostingPlanNames": {
  "value": [
    "ap-d-function1",
    "ap-d-function2"     
  ]
}
```

Or simply use two separate parameters:

```
"hostingPlanName1": {
  "value": "ap-d-function1"
}

"hostingPlanName2": {
  "value": "ap-d-function2"
}
```

If using arrays, the simplest option is to reference them as shown in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/data-types#arrays), e.g. to use the first value:

```
"someValue": "[parameters('hostingPlanNames')[0]]"
```

Or you can loop using a [copy element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-tutorial-create-multiple-instances?tabs=CLI%2Cazure-cli#edit-the-template) within your resource and use the copyIndex() function to access the array:

```
"resources": [
  {
    "type": "some/resource/type",
    "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanNames')[copyIndex()]]",
    ...
    "copy": {
      "name": "myCopy",
      "count": "2"
    }
  }
]
```

There are various other functions that can also be used with arrays, see [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-array).

Comment: Thanks a lot. How will then i access these names in variables in case of array? "variables": {
    "hostingPlanNames": "[parameters('hostingPlanNames')]",

Comment: Will edit my answer to show some ways of working with arrays.